# Telnet commands via PHP - extremely long execution time problem, using PHPTelnet class

Tags: php, telnet, fsockopen

I need to automate several functions of our systems, which unfortunately have no API, only telnet commands.

So, I found this: http://www.geckotribe.com/php-telnet/ which is essentially a Telnet class for PHP.

At first I had weird issues, as it was attempting to login too fast, so I added extra sleep(2) in between the connection, and entering of the username and password.

Now to the problem: It seems, that after executing one command which outputs only a single line, the next one (which is multi line output) hangs the system for anywhere from 2 minutes and 15 secs (on eclipse debug mode), to 1 min 20 secs on browser load (only after I forced timeout setting to 180 secs...).

The line on which it happens is: $r.=fread($this->fp,1000); in the DoCommand() function of the class.

Here is a pastebin link to the script I try to execute, as well as the output I eventually get (with modification to protect information..)

code: http://pastebin.com/TXEHWa05

Output: http://pastebin.com/mVFm5HM2

Any ideas how to debug the cause of this? so far I have never needed even a debugger in my projects :(
Ideally I'd want to finish executing 2-3 commands on telnet in 5 seconds max.. not more.
(cause once we figure this out, I'll add functionality to disconnect the user, etc..).

I hope someone more experienced with this kind of PHP usage using fsockopen can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop that this call invokes is reading 1000 bytes of data at a time until it receives all of the data. Its possible that the socket_get_status call is always returning a value for 'unread_bytes' and this just loops until your forced timeout invokes. Its possible the service on the other end is returning a rather large response, in which case you can increase the byte read length by 1000 each time it hangs up until you find a suitable number. Also, do a little debugging by var_dump()'ing out the results of fread and socket_get_status each time to see where its hanging up.

Comment: Thanks! I increased it to 8192 and now its ok, although it still takes a good 6-10 seconds to finish the whole program.

Comment: What is the meaning of this value? I mean, I understand it means how many chars to read, but is it really needed? seems to me it causes more trouble than it worth.
Is there any way to bypass it? making sure some day it wont stuck on 8193 chars...